# Is there any way to erase the first part of this string?

Tags: javascript, regex, string

The following code is returning this:
$100.00 - $209.00
but I need just the last value(without the dollar sign:
209.00

I'm sure that that's possible with regular expression.
Does someone know how to do it?

The variable comes from Handlebar.

```
<span class="round">
   {{price<?php echo $priceKey; ?>_formatted}}
</span>
```

I'm expecting to transform the original to 209.00

I have to use javascript.

It's not necessarily regular expression. Could be anything that solves the issue.

Thanks

Comment: You want to do it using php or JS ?

Comment: price.split('$')[1] or regex?

Comment: @CodeManiac I have to use javascript

Comment: This kind of work is more appropriate on the back end. To do it in JS you'll have to template the variable (which becomes trickier if you're looping), operate on it, then dynamically insert it into the HTML, or operate on the HTML *after* its been rendered, which will cause a slight flash. Might be easier to just do it right.

Answer (score 3):

If your string is always is of same nature you can use split

```js
let str = "$100.00 - $209.00"

let op = str.split('$').pop()

console.log(op)
```

You can use match

```
.*\$(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)
```

[image]

```js
let str = "$100.00 - $209.00"

let op = str.match(/.*\$(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)/)

console.log(op[1])
```

Comment: What tool did you use to generate the graphic?

Comment: @MichaelCrenshaw regex visualizer [Regulex](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5E(a%7Cb)*%3F%24)

Answer (score 1):

`'$100.00 - $209.00'.split('$')[2]` isn't regex, but maybe the simplicity makes it better.

```js
console.log('$100.00 - $209.00'.split('$')[2])
```

I use `[2]` instead of `[1]` because of [this behavior of the `.split` function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split#Description):

> If separator appears at the beginning or end of the string, or both, the array begins, ends, or both begins and ends, respectively, with an empty string.

Comment: is it [2] or [1] ?

Comment: [2]. The first element is an empty string, "split" before the first $.

Answer (score 1):

Another alternative (without a regular expression) is to use [String.slice()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/slice) in conjunction with [String.lastIndexOf()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/lastIndexOf):

```js
let str = document.querySelector(".round").innerText;
let formatted = str.slice(str.lastIndexOf("$") + 1);
console.log(formatted);
```

```css
.as-console {background-color:black !important; color:lime;}
```

```html
<span class="round">
   $100.00 - $209.00
</span>
```